# Function invocation issue

Tags: python, function, traceback

Hello I am having issues with a function invocation. Below is me code that is working for a function.

```
def get_flickr_data(search_data,photo_number=50):
    baseurl ="https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/"
    params_d={}
    params_d["tags"]= search_data
    params_d["per_page"]=photo_number
    params_d["format"]= "json"
    params_d["method"]= "flickr.photos.search"
    params_d["tag_mode"]= "all"
    params_d["api_key"] = FLICKR_KEY
    unique_indent = params_unique_combination(baseurl,params_d)
    if unique_indent in CACHE_DICTION:
        flickr_info = CACHE_DICTION[unique_indent]
    else:
        resp = requests.get(baseurl,params_d)
        python_flickr = json.loads(resp.text[14:-1])
        CACHE_DICTION[unique_indent] = python_flickr
        f = open(CACHE_FNAME,"w")
        cache_str_tmp = json.dumps(CACHE_DICTION)
        f.write(cache_str_tmp)
        f.close()
    return CACHE_DICTION[unique_indent]
```

I am trying to make an invocation to my get_flickr_data function with the input "mountains" (and 50 as the 2nd parameter). Then I want to save the result in the variable flickr_mountains_result.( side note I am not very good at functions so I am probably missing something)

```
get_flickr_data("mountains",50)
flickr_mountains_result = get_flickr_data
print flickr_mountains_result
```

Above is my code that is not working, I get the traceback TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '**getitem**'.

Comment: You could read somthing about functions before asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

This line is executing the function:

```
get_flickr_data("mountains",50)
```

To capture its results combine your first and second line:

```
flickr_mountains_result = get_flickr_data("mountains",50)
```

The value returned from your function is then [assigned to the variable](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex21.html).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
flickr_mountains_result = get_flickr_data("mountains",50)
print flickr_mountains_result
```

You have to capture the value returned by a function in a variable to use it after.
Read more about how functions work, and how to use them [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm), or any other tutorial for beginners you find!